# info.plist can not be saved after editing in react native

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native

The problem I have is when I edit the
**MyProject/ios/info.plist**
, I save it successfully. But when I try to open the project to see if the changes have been applied, it is only edited back to its default form. Does anyone know why this happens and how could it be definitively edited after adding anything?
Here you have more details with what I work:

**package.json:**

```js
{
  "name": "user",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "npm": "^5.7.1",
    "react": "16.3.0-alpha.2",
    "react-native": "0.54.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "23.0.0-alpha.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "4.0.0",
    "jest": "22.4.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.3.0-alpha.2"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

**info.plist before editing (default):**

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
 <key>LastAccessedDate</key>
 <date>2018-03-20T15:02:01Z</date>
 <key>WorkspacePath</key>
 <string>/Users/user/Documents/myproject/ios/myproject.xcodeproj</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

**info.plist after editing:**

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>LastAccessedDate</key>
    <date>2018-03-20T15:02:01Z</date>
    <key>WorkspacePath</key>
    <string>/Users/user/Documents/myproject/ios/myproject.xcodeproj</string>
</dict>
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I explain, when saving the changes made and recompile the application from scratch, the lines added in the info.plist disappear and only the default value remains.

However, if there's no solution, what can i add instead of

```js
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
```

to make `http` requests to IOS devices, is there a different way to do it?

Comment: Have you tried edit it from XCODE?

Comment: yes, i did it from Xcode, saved it, and re-open the simulator, and then i could see how my lines added disappeared suddenly.

Comment: I've the solution, i just did the steps that shows on [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/68646/how-do-i-unlock-a-plist-file-so-that-i-can-change-it) website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be only one root level dictionary in the file. So try this one instead:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>LastAccessedDate</key>
    <date>2018-03-20T15:02:01Z</date>
    <key>WorkspacePath</key>
    <string>/Users/user/Documents/myproject/ios/myproject.xcodeproj</string>
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
       <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
       <true/>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```